# Bent shift lever on Shimano Deore MTB shifter

Tags: shimano, shifter

I bent the shifter lever on my Deore shifter mech  and the bottom lever that would shift me into an easier gear is running into the lever above it when the bottom lever gets pressed in. If I try and move the top lever out of the way, I can successfully move the bottom lever and get clean shifts with the crisp click every time. Otherwise the bottom lever pushes on the top lever and the shift doesn’t complete. Hopefully the pictures show the misalignment.

Anyone have any good ideas on getting the lever bent back straight? I’m a decently strong guy and I’m trying pretty damn hard to straighten it back out and it’s not moving. I tried removing the bottom cover from the mech as well to use pliers to try and straighten it out to no avail.

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s the bottom lever that is bent right?

You are just going to have to find some way to apply leverage to the thumb lever, I.e., bigger wrench or pliers.

An approximately 30cm length of metal or stout plastic tube that just slips over the shift lever is ideal.

Be aware that the aluminum lever is going to be weaker at the spot it was bent and bent back.

Comment: I will give that a try. Need to make it to the hardware store to find something that length to add leverage. Just trying anything I can to not have to replace an otherwise perfectly functioning shifter!

Comment: A long screwdriver should do the trick, using the handlebar as a fulcrum/pivot.

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same problem, bent it in a crash. I took it apart, used pliers, tried my own strength... nothing worked. Then I tried the metal pipe option mentioned here, and it worked like a charm. I had a 1 meter piece of pipe lying in the garage. Got it bent back in seconds, working perfectly now. I suppose its weaker now but seems strong, if it breaks now then thats okay, I can get a new one then. But for now I am happy I have prolonged its lifespan. [image: Metal pipe bending deore shifter back into place]

Answer (score -1):

It is not necessary to look for a metal pipe of the required diameter. Any glass bottle with a standard narrow neck will do (For example, a beer bottle). Its neck is strong enough and has the required diameter to insert the shift lever into it. And a convenient extension will allow you to adjust the depth of threading the bottle onto the switch in order to more conveniently adjust the lever and the place where the force is applied.

*(Translated from original answer, see [timeline](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/posts/93451/timeline))*

Comment: Hi and welcome to Bicycles SE. I have translated your answer from Russian for better readability. Please be so kind and post in English so that moderators and privileged user don't have to do this manually all the time.

Comment: This answer refers to using a glass bottle. This seems odd if not even dangerous. @DoNuT I wonder if this could be a translation mishap?

Comment: @pateksan I was using Google Translate but the fact that it translates _glass bottle_ and _beer bottle_ makes it more than likely it was meant this way, I also checked with Bing and I get pretty much the same (even though Google does a better job of producing proper English). For everything beyond, I'd say we, we still have comments, a voting and flag/close function here to judge the actual content. It is very pragmatic and I'd use something to wrap the bottle for safety reasons, but I don't see it as a pure joke/junk answer. Still better to keep it like that than Cyrillic letters, imo.

Comment: @pateksan стеклянная бутылка is a glass bottle, there is no doubt about it, one does not need a high level of Russion for this. стекло is glass.

Comment: @DoNuT yeah I get that about flagging, voting etc. I added a comment to check that the answer is intended to say what it says. I got that confirmed and I can now vote with full peace of mind. Thanks

Comment: Just make sure the glass bottle is robust enough to handle the stress/strain without breaking.

Comment: Useful answer if the reader applies some common sense before applying it. We are all cyclists here; I would presume we are capable to making assessments around using a glass bottle and putting in safety mitigation.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the Russian comment. I did not think that my comment would cause such a heated discussion=D. In the age of the Internet and the built-in translator in almost any browser, I did not think that I needed to write in my crooked English). As for the glass bottle, you understood everything correctly. It's strong enough to break in your hand! But if you are afraid, you can use the seatpost tube)